# Input string is not correct format when trying to sum gridview column value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a common question but couldn't find any satisfactory ans.here's my gridview column value sum code and the type of value i am trying to sum is decimal.i want to sum total amount value and show it in textbox below gridview column value the 4th column i want to sum and it's type is decimal

[image: code]

```
public void TypeTotalAmount()
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < typeWiseGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += decimal.Parse(typeWiseGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
    }
    totalTextBox.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you check with the debugger whether there is may be a trailing space in `Text` ?

Comment: yes i tried two times,everytime i step into the exception line visual studio auto restarts

Comment: Before you step into the exception line, hoover with the mouse over the `Text` property and you should see the content

Answer (score 1):

use the `Value.Tostring()` property

```
 decimal sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

            {
                sum += decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you use the `RowDataBound` event instead of looping the cell contents. The problem with this approach is that the cell content is always a string. So if you were to format it like currency, you won't be able to convert it back to a decimal since the cell contents now also contains a currency symbol.

Say you use this for binding the GridView

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="totalFee" HeaderText="Total Fee" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" />
```

The cell now contains a string in this format `€ 179,23`. So if you would loop it now you'll always get the `input string is....` error

By using the OnRowDataBound event you add the values of the source data, not the (formatted) data bound to the GridView.

```
decimal sum = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        sum += Convert.ToDecimal(row["totalFee"]);

        TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am having an exception object reference is not set to an instance of object in sum+= line,i have used iemtemplate for all the gridview columns,also there is no dataformatstrings

Comment: You do need to change `row["totalFee"]` to your actual column name from the database.